# why is 64 added to the end of a typcast transformation?

Tags: sql

```
    Select 
usertype, CONCAT(start_station_name, "to", end_station_time) As route
Count (*)
Round (avg(Cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) As duration
```

--example typecast trip duration to integer includes 64.. but why?

Comment: Which SQL database is this? Each dialect is substantially different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like BigQuery code.

In BigQuery, the integer type is called `int64`, meaning that it has 64 bits (or 8 bytes).

I'm not sure why it calls this `int64` rather than simply `int`.  I imagine it will disappear one day.  It is a non-standard name and adds a needless inconsistency with other databases.